# Sending emails during Capistrano deployment using Rails 5, Ruby 2.4, and Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3, ruby-2.4

Capistrano 3.7.2, Rails 5.0.2, and Ruby 2.4.0 to be specific. The error I get occurs after `Execute load:defaults`:

```
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Rescuable
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionmailer-5.0.2/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:6:in `<module:Rescuable>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionmailer-5.0.2/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:4:in `<module:ActionMailer>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionmailer-5.0.2/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionmailer-5.0.2/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:8:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionmailer-5.0.2/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/rails_5_test_app/config/deploy/notify/cap_mailer.rb:5:in `require'
/Users/username/rails_5_test_app/config/deploy/notify/cap_mailer.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config/deploy.rb:4:in `require'
config/deploy.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.7.2/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `load'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.7.2/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.7.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:32:in `untrusted!'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/delegate.rb:83:in `method_missing'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.7.2/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.7.2/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.7.2/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/cap:22:in `load'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => staging
```

I'm about to start upgrading my Rails 4 apps to Rails 5, and decided to do a small test app to make sure all my gems are working. Everything is fine, except for the code I've been using since Rails 2 to send emails during a Capistrano deploy, which results in this error when I try to require or load the mailer code; line 4 of deploy.rb is the require. If I comment that out and set a flag to not send an email, the deploy works perfectly.

The mailer code (based off of something posted by Mislav Marohnić years ago):

cap_mailer.rb:

```
require "action_mailer"

yaml_config = File.read("config/email.yml")
email_config = YAML.load(yaml_config)
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = email_config['delivery_method'] # currently set to :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: email_config['smtp_settings']['address'],
    port: email_config['smtp_settings']['port'],
    notify_emails: email_config['notify_emails']
}
ActionMailer::Base.view_paths = File.dirname(__FILE__)

class CapMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => 'App Deployment <app_deploy@my.org>'

  def deploy_notification(cap_vars)
    @now = Time.now

    set :body, ENV['comment']

    mail(:to => fetch(:notify_emails),
         :subject => "#{fetch(:human_readable_application_name)} - Changes to application on #{fetch(:stage)} server at #{fetch(:host)}"
    )
  end

  def test_email
    @now = Time.now

    mail(:to => "developer@my.org",
         :subject => "#{fetch(:human_readable_application_name)} - Capistrano test email #{@now.strftime("on %m/%d/%Y at %I:%M %p")}"
    )

  end

end
```

All I can dig up online are references to very similar mailing set-ups (e.g. https://gist.github.com/johnthethird/955917) that were written for older versions of everything. There are several gems written to send mail during Capistrano deploys, but they have the same problem with being really old ([capistrano-notifier](https://github.com/gofullstack/capistrano-notifier), [capistrano_mailer](https://github.com/pboling/capistrano_mailer)).

So at this point I'm stuck. Googling `NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Rescuable` suggested maybe this is a config problem, but I don't know what to look for there. ActiveSupport::Rescuable IS there in my Rails installation; I double-checked. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to load ActiveSupport first, like this:

```
require "active_support"
require "action_mailer"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Can you explain why this is necessary? And/or why it only became necessary in Rails 5? I haven't run into anything like this before.

Comment: Well, based on the error, ActionMailer depends on `ActiveSupport::Rescuable` but it apparently doesn't load it itself. This seems like an oversight (bug) with ActionMailer 5.0.2 and I would report it on the Rails GitHub.